# Network - testing connectivity [Python or C]

Tags: python, networking

Let's say I want to see if my ftp server is online, how could I do this in a program. 
Also, what do you think would be the easiest least intrusive way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to the port of your FTP server to see if it is accepting connections.

If you want to go one step further you could send an `ls` command and check that you get a sensible response.

If you want to do it in Python you can use [ftplib](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html).

Comment: What if I wanted to do this to just any computer, to see if it is online?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would try nmap first to do this, http://nmap.org.

```
nmap $HOSTNAME -p 21
```

To test port 21 (ftp) on a list of servers in python might look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
from socket import *   

host_list=['localhost', 'stackoverflow.com']

port=21 # (FTP port)

def test_port(ip_address, port, timeout=3):
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(timeout)
    result = s.connect_ex((ip_address, port))
    s.close()
    if(result == 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False

for host in host_list:
    if test_port(gethostbyname(host), port):
        print 'Successfully connected to',
    else:
        print 'Failed to connect to',
    print '%s on port %d' % (host, port)
```